# Hazelcast does not seems to be disabling multicast

Tags: hazelcast

I am trying to setup 3 Hazelcast instances running on individual VMs on EC2. I disabled multicast and enabled tcp ip in hazelcast-3.7.2/bin/hazelcast.xml. But hazelcast does not seems to be disabling multicast. It still starts with multicast and does not honor the tcp ip configuration in hazelcast.xml. Here is the config.

```
<multicast enabled="false">
    <multicast-group>224.2.2.3</multicast-group>
    <multicast-port>54327</multicast-port>
</multicast>
<tcp-ip enabled="true">
    <interface>10.0.255.11</interface>
    <member-list>
        <member>10.0.255.11</member>
        <member>10.0.255.12</member>
        <member>10.0.255.13</member>
    </member-list>
</tcp-ip>
```

Sometimes it works and sometimes it starts in multicast. Your help to identify the issue is appreciated.

Comment: If you are running on EC2, why don't you just make use of aws configurations and disable tcp-ip ?

Comment: please attach a startup script